# Running Docker Container in Opendaylight

Tags: networking, docker, bind

After typing the command

docker run -d -p 6633:6633 -p 8181:8181 -p 8101:8101 --name=opendaylight glefevre/opendaylight

I am getting an error

dd66ef3db5e769c52fa2c725234fa4dc31192e310abfcddf576ad9de88d5a61d
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint opendaylight (f36a904bceb9abe018bb6de924858a7879c379951d7b6f18687c3cb6c11e4dab): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8181: bind: address already in use.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your machine already use port 8181.
Try using other port or check what uses that port.

Comment: Can you help me how to use other port?

Comment: Something like this : `docker run -d -p 6633:6633 -p 8182:8181 -p 8101:8101 --name=opendaylight glefevre/opendaylight`, where the format is `-p $hostport:$containterport`

Comment: To know which process is using 8181, use `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8181`

Comment: Althought when you use unused port you’ll need to allow this port in your firewall. ‘sudo ufw allow <port>’ will add desired port to firewall.